# Ignoring stderr of process

Tags: haskell, process, stderr

This should be a simple question, but so far I haven’t found any direct answer to it: **how does one ignore the `stderr` (or `stdout`) of a Haskell process using the `process` library**? For instance, let’s say I have the following:

```hs
let proc = (shell "dir /z") {
      std_in  = UseHandle stdin
    , std_out = CreatePipe
    }
(_, out, _, rProc) <- createProcess Proc
exitCode <- waitForProcess rProc
```

(Side note: in Windows, I do know that `dir` doesn’t have a `/z` switch. That’s why I chose it — so I could get some interesting output on `stderr`.)

Doing this just causes `stderr` to be printed to the console. Now let’s say I want to ignore `stderr`. How do I do this?

The only clue I have found is in [this part](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/process-1.6.5.1/docs/System-Process.html#t:StdStream) of the `process` documentation:

> **`NoStream`** Close the stream's file descriptor without passing a Handle. On POSIX systems this may lead to strange behavior in the child process because attempting to read or write after the file has been closed throws an error. This should only be used with child processes that don't use the file descriptor at all. If you wish to ignore the child process's output you should either create a pipe and drain it manually or pass a `Handle` that writes to `/dev/null`.

This is somewhat helpful, but still leaves some questions unanswered. On non-POSIX systems, is `NoStream` OK to use? It refers to creating a pipe then draining it, but I can’t find any information on how to do this? And `/dev/null` is `NUL` on Windows, except when you’re using MSYS or Cygwin, when it’s `/dev/null` again (I think) — so I want to avoid that.

So to reiterate my question: what is the recommended, OS-agnostic way to ignore the `stderr` of a process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one correct way:

```
import Control.Concurrent
import Control.Exception
import System.IO
import System.Process

forceGetContents :: String -> IO ()
forceGetContents s = evaluate (length s) >> return ()

main = do
    outMVar <- newEmptyMVar
    let proc = (shell "dir /z") {
          std_in  = UseHandle stdin
        , std_out = CreatePipe
        , std_err = CreatePipe
        }
    (_, Just out, Just err, rProc) <- createProcess proc
    forkIO (hGetContents err >>= forceGetContents)
    forkIO $ do
        s <- hGetContents out
        forceGetContents s
        putMVar outMVar s
    exitCode <- waitForProcess rProc
    outContents <- takeMVar outMVar
    putStr outContents -- or whatever
```

Some things worth noting from comments on a deleted answer:

1. You should fork a thread to drain the error pipe. Otherwise, if there are many errors, the process you started may be killed before it can print them all, leading to a confusing debugging session.
2. *If* you are going to `waitForProcess`, you should fork a thread to drain the output pipe. Otherwise it may be killed before it can print everything it wants to, giving incomplete output.
3. This will store the entire output of the process (though not the entire contents of the error stream) in memory. This can be quite expensive.
4. `forceGetContents` is a good way to force a `String` returned by an `hGetContents` to be fully evaluated, but there are other `String`-producers which may need a more involved forcing function. See also `rnf` from the `deepseq` package.

You can address both (2) and (3) if there is a protocol that you know the process will follow where you will know when it is done producing output. Then you can stream the output (reducing memory pressure for bits that can be discarded early), and can delay the `waitForProcess` until you know it is done outputting (avoiding the need to fork a thread to drain the output -- though still requiring a forked thread for the errors!).

Comment: Why is it a problem if the process is killed before the output is drained? Shouldn't the OS have buffered it all in the pipe?

Comment: It definitely makes sense to fork a thread to drain the errors (or, probably better), use Yuji Yamamoto's suggestion), but doing that for the output seems unfortunate.

Comment: @dfeuer Pipe buffers are generally 4KB or so. So if there's more than 4KB of output, no, the OS won't buffer it all.

Comment: I’ve read through this answer, but I still don’t understand point (1). If you’re just ignoring the errors, why should it matter if the process is killed before it prints them all? Also, for (2), if `waitForProcess` is used, why would the output pipe be killed before the program is finished?

Comment: @bradrn It matters because errors and actual output can be interleaved. It follows that if it's killed before it finishes printing an error because its error pipe fills up, there may also be output that you never see, because the program was killed before it could print it!

Comment: @bradrn If you `waitForProcess` without draining the output pipe concurrently, then the output pipe can fill up, and the OS will kill the program if that happens.

Comment: @bradrn It's pretty easy to test this stuff yourself. Just write a tiny C program with a loop that goes 10,000 times or so and does `fprintf(stderr, "a line to stderr\n"); fprintf(stdout, "a line to stdout\n");` each time through the loop (so that it 1. produces a lot of output to both handles and 2. interleaves the two). Then you can try changing the code from this answer in the ways you're proposing and observe how it fails.

Comment: @DanielWagner That clears up a lot of questions I had! So does this mean that if I’m running a program with a very small amount of output (only a couple of lines), then it should be possible to do everything in one thread and leave `stderr` undrained?

Comment: As far as I can tell, you're wrong about the standard out. If I read it slowly, then the buffer will indeed fill up, but the OS won't kill the other process--it'll just block it till there's more room in the buffer. So directing the errors to the void (with `nullStream` or a new thread), then just reading/processing the output and finishing by waiting for the process should work.

Comment: @dfeuer As discussed in the answer, blocking is also one possibility. It depends on how the program is written. Blocking is just about as bad, though: it means that if the pipe fills up, and your `waitForProcess` happens before you drain the pipe, you've got a deadlock where `waitForProcess` is waiting for the pipe to drain and you won't drain the pipe until `waitForProcess` returns. Yes, if you read/process the output instead of using `hGetContents` that suffices -- as I said in the answer as well!

Comment: @bradrn Sure. Gonna be pretty annoying to track down this bug once you forget about that caveat, though!

Comment: @DanielWagner You’re right, but I feel fairly confident in my particular situation. For context, I’m trying to read the output of `stty`, which as far as I know only ever outputs a few lines.

Answer (score 2):

I guess [`nullStream` in typed-process package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/typed-process-0.2.6.0/docs/System-Process-Typed.html#v:nullStream) is what you are looking for.

Comment: This is definitely what I would use normally, but unfortunately for various reasons I can’t use `typed-process`. But thanks for the answer anyway!